# Probability of one person in a group of 3 getting their coats returned to them if they were mixed randomly within a group of 30 people with 30 coats?

Tags: probability

So I got a question which I found was similar to the birthday paradox, but not sure exactly which way to go.
The question is as follows:
I go with 2 friends to a birthday party with 27 other people. Each of us gives our coat to the servant. The servant mixes up our coats. What is the probability that at least one of us gets our coat returned.
I tried to find the probability that none of us get our coats back, but the use of one of the 3 in our group put me off.
How would I solve this?

Comment: You're doing it right.  The probability that at least one gets the right coat is $1$ minus the probability that all get the wrong coat.

Comment: Look up derangements.  These are permutations where no element stays in place.

Comment: The probability is $\frac{2353}{24360} \approx 0.0965$.  I'll put down an answer shortly.

Comment: It's useful to know about [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), and the process is the same, although it has to be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret the problem as asking about the probability that at least one of us gets *one of* our coats. Then the probability is simply:
$$1-\frac{\binom{27}3}{\binom{30}3},$$
where the last term is the probability that all three coats belong to some of other 27 people.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasonable ways to the solution, each giving the same result.  One is by means of the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  Label the people A, B, C, $\ldots$.  We wish to calculate the number of coat arrangements in which at least one of A, B, and C gets their own coat back.  What we can do is calculate the number of arrangements in which A gets their coat back, the number in which B gets their coat back, and the number in which C gets their coat back.  Then we add them all up.

Of course, in so doing, we've doubly counted the cases where both A and B get their coats back, or where both A and C get their coats back, or where both B and C get their coats back.  So we should subtract these out.

Unfortunately, now we've subtracted out an extra time the cases where A, B, and C all get their coats back.  So we have to add that back in.

All this sounds more laborious than it is.  The number of arrangements in which A gets their coat back is $29!$; likewise for B and for C.  The number of arrangements in which both A and B gets their coats back is $28!$; likewise for A and C, and for B and C.  And finally the number of arrangements in which A, B, and C all get their coats back is $27!$.

So the number we want is

$$
3 \times 29! - 3 \times 28! + 27!
$$

---

Another way of approaching the problem is to divide it into four cases.  Where do the coats of A, B, and C end up?  They can either end up in the three handed back to A, B, and C, or they can end up being handed back to the other $27$ people.  Let us count the number of ways in which *none* of them gets their coat back, and then we'll subtract this from $30!$, the total number of arrangements.

- None of the three coats gets handed back to A, B, or C.  The three coats they do get back can be handed back in any of $3! = 6$ orders, so there are $\binom{3}{0} \times \binom{27}{3} \times 6 \times 27!$ suitable arrangements.
- One of the three coats gets handed back to A, B, or C.  Of the $3! = 6$ possible orders in which they get their coats back, $4$ do not give the coat back to the right one, so there are $\binom{3}{1} \times \binom{27}{2} \times 4 \times 27!$ suitable arrangements.
- Two of the three coats get handed back to A, B, or C.  Of the $3! = 6$ possible orders in which they get their coats back, $3$ give neither of the two coats back to the right person, so there are $\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{27}{1} \times 3 \times 27!$ suitable arrangements.
- All three of the coats get handed back to A, B, and C.  Of the $3! = 6$ possible orders in which they get their coats back, just $2$ give the coats back so that none of them gets their own coat back, so there are $\binom{3}{3} \times \binom{27}{0} \times 2 \times 27!$ suitable arrangements.

So the number we want is

\begin{align}
30! & - \binom{3}{0} \times \binom{27}{3} \times 6 \times 27! \\
& - \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{27}{2} \times 4 \times 27! \\
& - \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{27}{1} \times 3 \times 27! \\
& - \binom{3}{3} \times \binom{27}{0} \times 2 \times 27!
\end{align}

---

Both of these result in the value $25621509816834382634287104000000$; when we divide this by $30!$, the total number of arrangements, we get

$$
\frac{3 \times 29! - 3 \times 28! + 27!}{30!} = \frac{25621509816834382634287104000000}{265252859812191058636308480000000} = \frac{2353}{24360} \approx 0.0965
$$